# How do I push a new user to a Firebase Database using Dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I'm trying add a new user to the database (pictured below) but I'm having difficulty pushing the data to the db. I already have firebase authentication setup and that works fine. When a new user registers they are added to the authenticated list but not the db and I would like it to do both. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

```
RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Register',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            dynamic result = await _auth
                                .registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                              final userReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');
                              userReference.push().set({
                                'email': email,
                                'firstname': fname,
                                'lastname': lname,
                                'chatrooms': cRoomsList,
                                'showsList': showsList,
                              });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method `_auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` , 
try using: `_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);`, this method will also return the reference to the user.

Let me know if this helps!